# Is there any way to update maximum characters limit in Levenshtein (Postgresql)?

Tags: postgresql, levenshtein-distance

I am using fuzzystrmatch extension in Postgresql 14.

When I am running below query, it is giving this error message:

**ERROR:  levenshtein argument exceeds maximum length of 255 characters**

`SELECT levenshtein('xxxxxxxx', 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY');`

Referred this document, https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/fuzzystrmatch.html
which says, that *Both source and target can be any non-null string, with a maximum of 255 characters.*

But I have this requirement to support any number of characters for levenshtein. Is there any way, I can update this max length in Postgresql for levenshtein?

I referred few Postgresql and fuzzystrmatch documents which says that we can't have more than 255 characters.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/fuzzystrmatch.html

But I am looking for a way, if this max length can be controlled in Postgresql.

Comment: Read the source code of the function and create your own version.

Comment: As @Laurenz_Albe says, PostGreSQL is a free open source RDBMS. If you want a Levenshtein function that can works on an unlimited number of chars, you need only to modify the source code of this function, then recompile...

Answer (score 0):

If you are not looking for the exact number of permutations but are simply willing to do a similarity search/match you can use the similarity function in pg_trgm.

```
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS pg_trgm;

SELECT field
FROM table
WHERE similarity(field, '{{value}}') >= 0.95;
```